# How to change state value when checkbox change using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im currently using React for a project where i work and i'm struggling binding state with the form i'm creating. So i have this :

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        proofDivulgation: false,
        proofDivulgationFedex: false,
        proofDivulgationMail: false,
        noticeRecidivism: false,
        noticeRecidivismFedex: false,
        noticeRecidivismEmail: false,
        fedexAccount: '',
        emergyContact: false

    };
```

And i want to change those booleans whenever i'll modify a checkbox ( the value of those booleans should be the same as the checked value of a checkbox ).
I got this React component too

`<Toggle defaultChecked={this.state.proofDivulgation} onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange(this.state.proofDivulgation)} />`

and this is the method attached to the onChange event :

```
handleCheckboxChange: function(booleanToSwitch){
  console.log(booleanToSwitch);
  this.replaceState({booleanToSwitch : true})
},
```

which give me this error : `replaceState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as withinrender). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.`

Is there any work-around i could do ? I simply need a basic function that'll invert the boolean value of a state passed as a parameters

Answer (score 1):

You are calling that function immediately, not on change.

1. React runs `render`;
2. It finds an `onChange` parameter;
3. If it's a function reference then nothing happens;
4. If it's a function call then the function is called when the code runs and the result is passed as the callback to `onChange`;
5. When you click on the checkbox that function reference (callback) is called;

What your code does is set the return value of `this.handleCheckboxChange(this.state.proofDivulgation)` as the callback for `onChange`.

What you need is this:

```
handleCheckboxChange: function(booleanToSwitch) {
  return function(event) {
    console.log(booleanToSwitch);
    this.replaceState({booleanToSwitch : true})
  };
},
```

Also I'm pretty sure you'll need

```
this.state[booleanToSwitch] = true;
```

instead.